# specify wrapper method prefix for C# SWIG

Tags: c#, swig

When SWIG (using C#) wraps a method, say

```
void foo();
```

it will generate a wrapper method with a `CSharp_` prefix like this:

```
SWIGEXPORT void SWIGSTDCALL CSharp_foo() {
  foo();
}
```

Is it possible to specify/override this prefix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to change this at runtime -- as far as I can make it out, this is set in file csharp.cxx, line:

```
Swig_name_register("wrapper", "CSharp_%f");
```

So you'd need to change this in some way and recompile SWIG.